# Why was this question auto-protected?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I just noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524053/simplest-way-to-apply-css-background-color-to-nth-child-3-to-10) was automatically protected.

There are 5 deleted answers, 2 of which were from users with < 10 rep. As far as I know, it takes deleting 3 such answers for auto-protection to be triggered.

The question was protected at around 10 am UTC, several hours after the numerous answers were posted. So it can't be due to too many answers either (although there are a fair amount of answers from low-rep users).

There are no flags on either the question or any of the answers.

The only thing I can think of that might have led to the question being protected is the fact that 6 of the answers (including deleted ones) were downvoted, 5 of which were downvoted just a minute before the question was protected. But, unless something has changed, I don't think downvoting answers alone would lead to a question being automatically protected.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: There is a third not-yet-deleted post by a low-rep user on there, as well as downvoted answers by <80 rep users. The number of posts may also be a factor.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226619/auto-protect-questions-that-get-more-than-n-answers-from-new-users-in-a-24-hour

Comment: It got auto protected 22 seconds after an edit you made. Not sure what triggered it though.